# Outbound format for SMS to Jamaica from US

Tags: twilio, sms-gateway

Jamaica Country phone code is 1876  As an example: the Jamaica number received from (876) 320-6990.  Jamaica has the following are codes 718, 347, 929, and 917.  NYC also has an are code 718, 347, 929, and 917.  If I want to return an SMS to Jamaica what is the format 18768763206990 or 18763206990 ?  How does it know its not New York? What is the format for Jamaica?

I have not sent a message yet.

Comment: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179888-How-do-I-dial-international-numbers-with-Twilio-

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to return an SMS to Jamaica what is the format
> 18768763206990 or 18763206990

It would be the second option: `+18763206990`

Also, please check out [Twilio Jamaica Guidelines for SMS](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/guidelines/jm/sms). Two-way SMS is not supported.